# How do I get more flowers?

Tags: happy-street

Flowers are necessary components for dyes, flower bouquets, and the black lotus - but they seem to spawn very slowly.  What can I do to get more to spawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not obvious to me from the tutorial, but in the forest section you have the option to plant or sell "tree spawners".  Flowers and mushrooms only spawn in empty locations, where no trees are planted.  If you want more flowers, sell or bag up all your tree spawners.  If you want more wood, plant more trees or pull some out that you stored in your bag.  Trees are pretty cheap, so even if you sell and rebuy over and over it isn't a very big financial penalty.

Comment: If you want more of both, simply purchase new land in the forest.